# Indesign how to fix inconsistent margins in book

Tags: adobe-indesign, book, margin

I'm using **InDesign CS5** and I am editing a book.

I know I was wanting to try out different margins, so I must have messed it up there.

My **Chapter 1** styles page has different margins from a lot of the other chapters in my book; I've synchronized everything diligently all along...

I can't figure out a way to get the margins synched.

> Is there any way to fix this?  Help!